# How do I link the iphones time to change a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to link the time on the iphone such as midnight to change the text of a UILabel to something else anyone help out?

Ive looked through the NSTimer and found nothing that works any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(update:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And...

```
- (void) update:(NSTimer *) timer {
   myLabel.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date] dateStyle: NSDateFormatterLongStyle timeStyle: NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two other ways: use -[performSelector:withObject:aterDelay:]  (and NSObject has a class method to cancel such, or better,

your appDelegate can implement:

```
-(void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)app;
```

which will get called at midnight, carrier time update,  and daylight savings time change